# Floating Action Button и CardView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, cardview

Как прикрепить Floating Action Button из библиотеки поддержки к CardView так, что при прокрутке, с помощью ScrollView, кнопка уходила вверх вместе с карточкой?

Comment: Просто поместить FAB внутрь карточки....

Comment: Нужно чтоб она выступала за край карточки, цеплял ее с помощью anchor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместите `CardView` и `FAB` внутрь `FrameLayout`, коий будет уже внутри `ScrollView` - так вы сможете поместить FAB поверх CardView как угодно с помощью `layout_gravity` и, т.к. они будут оба внутри ScrollView, то оба будут скролиться вместе

Comment: Спасибо,все получилось

Comment: Скорее всего `CoordinatorLayout` и `layout_anchorGravity` :)